# How do I find a specific table in my EDMX model quickly?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework-4, edmx, edmx-designer

I was wondering if anyone knows a quicker way to find a table in the EDMX model than just scrolling through the diagram and looking for the thing. Our database has around 50 tables in it and when I'm looking for a specific one it's just a chore to see where VS put the thing.

I'm using VS 2010 for the purpose of this question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit: Thank you for your quick answers. marc_s, I know yours was first, but it took me a while to figure out what you meant. Bob Horn's answer was more complete with all the steps involved clearly laid out. I appreciate the time from all three of you.

Comment: Btw, sometimes it is necessary to find something quickly in .edmx using XML Editor. Would be nice all the xml would always be sorted inside .edmx file: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4142937-sort-and-autoformat-xml-inside-edmx-files-before

Answer (score 192, accepted):

**Click in an open area of the designer:**

[image]

**Go to the Properties tab:**

[image]

**In the dropdown box at the top, select your table. You should then see it highlighted in the designer.**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me in VS2015 professional. Clicking on the empty area only shows a single entry in the "Property" window, which is the ConceptualEntityModel.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out this method doesn't work on *.edmx files.

Comment: If you change the Fill color on the properties once you select the table, you can see it much easier on the table view.

Answer (score 62):

In main menu select View > Other Windows > Entity Data Model Browser (it usually opens in the same panel as Solution explorer).

You can navigate the tree list or type the table in text box.

[image: Entity data model browser]

Answer (score 14):

If you go to the `Properties` window in Visual Studio 2010, you'll see an alphabetically sorted list of **entity types** (e.g. your tables) in your EDMX - pick the one you're interested in, and the visual designer should realign itself to actually show that table in view:

[image]

Comment: As of VS 2017 this no longer works on DB-first edmx.

Answer (score 13):

In the "model browser" you can right click the Table and choose "Show in diagram" in the context menu

Comment: +1 For some reason my EDMX is a little broken, The diagram shows fine, but the properties drop down does not show any entities. This method works great.

Answer (score 10):

1. Right click on ampty place of Designer view
2. Select "Model browser"
   [image]

3)Select talbe form menu -> it will be selected in designer:

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer!